# Keep the code running while a video is displayed

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

So I am trying to code up something that keeps a video running until a condition is met and some processes are done and new video is loaded immediately after these processes. These processes should continue without closing the current video and should only close the current video when the new video is loaded and ready for vizualization.

This is best formulated by an example as given below:

```
import numpy as np 
import os 
import pygame 
import cv2
import time 

def play_video(vid_loc):
    pygame.init()
    infos = pygame.display.Info()
    screen_size = (infos.current_w, infos.current_h)

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(vid_loc) 
    frame_counter =0
    while(True):

        ret, frame = cap.read()
        frame_counter += 1

        if frame_counter == cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT):
            frame_counter = 0 
            cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 0)

        frame= cv2.resize(frame,screen_size)
        cv2.namedWindow('image', flags=cv2.WINDOW_GUI_NORMAL)
        cv2.setWindowProperty("image", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN,cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
        cv2.imshow('image',frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(1000) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()                

vid_loc = ["home/odd.ogv", "home/even.ogv"]

while True:
    n = random.randint(1, 100)
    if n%2 == 0:
        play_video(vid_loc[1])    
    else:
        play_video(vid_loc[0])
    time.sleep(10)
```

So this code generates a random number and checks if it is a even number or not. If even it runs a different video and if odd another video. My expectation with this code was to keep the random number being generated every
     10 second and keep the video running while the "while loop" runs again , generates another random number and checks if it is even or not without closing the video. If the number is odd , another video is run immediately after current video is closed. However this code would just keep the video running in loop as intended but does not generate another random number.

It basically gets stuck at cv2.imshow until "q" key is pressed and only then the "while loop" runs again.

Comment: you have 2 while loops with true as conditions... you should merge both in one loop which calculates the number and if a condition is met re loads the other video and in any case shows a frame of the current loaded video. If you want to preserve the frame it was, maybe you should have 2 objects, one for each video and just change the object being used

Comment: You should change the way you stop the while loop in `play_video`. Is there anything like `cv2.waitTime(...)`? If not you may stop `play_video` if `frame_counter` is greater than some value. Another option is to start `play_video` in a separate thread (or process) and communicate with it using queues. Or you may simulate key press.